# Duvida com o posicionamento do Draggable

Tags: php, html

estou precisando tirar uma dúvida com vocês!
Eu estou criando um Painel para Administrar um site, mas estou com dificuldade de descobrir, o porque quando posiciono uma imagem na escala que desejada, mas ao atualiza-la ela fica na posição desejada na página do site ou seja na página de destino, mas fica exatamente a medida de sua largura à direita no Painel Adm.

Bem como não sei se consegui me expressar ao ponto de me entenderem a minha dúvida, estou anexando o endereço de acesso para os amigos verificarem o que esta acontecendo

Página do Painel Adm:
http://www.buziosnegocios.com.br/teste/admin/painel/topo.php

Página de destino (Site):
http://www.buziosnegocios.com.br/teste/topo.php

Publico também o código da página do Painel Adm. para analise.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function () {

 // Posicionamento do LogoTipo
 $('#logoWrapper').draggable({
    drag: function (e) {
        var offset = $(this).find('img').offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;
        $('#posXimg').val(xPos);
        $('#posYimg').val(yPos);
    }
});

// Tamanho do LogoTipo
$('#logo').resizable({
    resize: function (event, ui) {
        var endW = $(this).outerWidth();
        var endH = $(this).outerHeight();

        $('#posWimg').val(endW);
        $('#posHimg').val(endH);

    }
});

// Posicionamento da Barra Menu
$('#menuWrapper').draggable({
    drag: function (e) {
        var offset = $(this).find('ul').offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;
        $('#posXul').val(xPos);
        $('#posYul').val(yPos);
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0 auto; background:#FFF;">

<div style="margin:0 auto; height:130px; width:1024px; background:#CCC;">

<div id="logoWrapper">
<?php
$logo = $_POST['logo'];
$hori_logo = $_POST['hori_logo'];
$vert_logo = $_POST['vert_logo'];
$larg_logo = $_POST['larg_logo'];
$altu_logo = $_POST['altu_logo'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topo");
$res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>

<img width="<?php echo $res['larg_logo'];?>" height="<?php echo $res['altu_logo'];?>" title="LogoTipo" src="../../upload/<?php echo $res['logo'];?>" id="logo" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="cursor: move; position:absolute; left: <?php echo $res['hori_logo'];?>px; top: <?php echo $res['vert_logo'];?>px;" />
</div>

<div style="position:absolute; cursor:move; left: <?php echo $res['hori_menu'];?>px; top: <?php echo $res['vert_menu'];?>px;" id="menuWrapper">
<?php //include "menu/barra_menu.php"; ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php if(isset($_POST['enter'])){

$logo = $_POST['logo'];
$hori_logo = $_POST['hori_logo'];
$vert_logo = $_POST['vert_logo'];
$larg_logo = $_POST['larg_logo'];
$altu_logo = $_POST['altu_logo'];

$update = mysql_query("UPDATE topo SET hori_logo = '$hori_logo', vert_logo = '$vert_logo', larg_logo = '$larg_logo', altu_logo = '$altu_logo', hori_menu = '$hori_menu', vert_menu = '$vert_menu'");

if($update == ''){

echo "<script language='javascript'>
window.alert('Erro ao atualizar dados!!!');
</script>";
}else{
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= ../painel/topo.php'>
<script language='javascript'>
window.alert('Dados atualizados com sucesso!');
</script>";
}}
?>
```

Precisando de algo mais, basta pedir que estarei publicando o que precisarem para que possam me ajudar a solucionar esse meu problema de posicionamento da imagem na página do Painel Adm.

Já agradecendo a atenção de todos, com um forte abraço.

Comment: Ficou um pouco complicado de saber qual o seu real problema. Se for algo relacionado ao jQuery, veja os exemplos do site, aprendi muito de jQuery por ele https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Olá Leonardo bom dia!
Peço desculpas, pois realmente ficou um pouco complicado a minha pergunta, mas vamos lá, vou tentar te explicar.
Nesse endereço  (http://www.buziosnegocios.com.br/teste/admin/painel/topo.php) eu movo o logotipo para a posição que desejo e atualizo.
Mas quando você faz a comparação do posicionamento com a página de destino no endereço (http://www.buziosnegocios.com.br/teste/topo.php), ela esta na posição desejada. Já no Painel ela fica sempre à direita de onde ela deveria estar. Dê uma testada nos endereços aqui mencionados, para ver o que esta acontecendo. Abraço!!!

Answer (score 1):

Isso é porque está a ser aplicada a propriedade `position: relative;` juntamente com o id `#logoWrapper` na página do [Painel Administrativo](http://www.buziosnegocios.com.br/teste/admin/painel/topo.php), que suponho que seja por causa da `class="ui-draggable"` implementada nesta mesma linha pelo `jQuery-UI`.

Para resolveres este problema, basta fazeres com que o id `#logoWrapper` seja `relativo` desde o inicio adicionando o CSS abaixo à tua folha de estilos, assim este será sempre relativo fazendo este problema desaparecer. E depois basta então colocar o valor `left:0;` como posição inicial do logo, em vez de - `left:173px;`.

```
#logoWrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

ou directamente no HTML:

```
<div id="logoWrapper" style="position:relative;">
```

Comment: Eu estava colocando esta **<div id="logoWrapper"> ** por dentro dessa **<div style="margin:0 auto; height:130px; width:1024px; background:#CCC;">** outra, e isso estava causando a diferença entres as páginas. Agora pergunto aos amigos, como poderia faze-las funcionarem juntas, ou seja uma <div> dentro da outra, sem dar a diferença de posicionamento?
Se alguem puder me dar uma dica, ficarei grato!

Comment: Isso não tem lá muito sentido @MuriloCabral ... até porque essa `div` anterior ao `logo-Wrapper` nem sequer tem razões ou atributos para fazer tal coisa, e ela está presente nas duas páginas com os mesmos atributos. O problema disso está aonde eu já mencionei na minha resposta. Você já experimentou fazer o que eu disse minha resposta?

Comment: Quanto à parte das **"duas 2 divs funcionarem uma dentro da outra"** não entendi bem o que você quis dizer com isso, mas essas `divs` até deveriam ser transformadas numa só, porque a primeira `div` não está ali a fazer nada, esses mesmos atributos podem ser atribuídos ao `id="logoWrapper"`. Exemplo: `<div id="logoWrapper" style="position:relative; margin:0 auto; height:130px; width:1024px; background:#CCC;">`